# "certificate signed by unknown authority" after resintalling LXD

Tags: terraform, ssl-certificate, lxd

I'm getting this error after purging lxd and reinstalling:

```
lxd_network.singlenode: Refreshing state... [id=singlenode] 

Error: Unable to create client for remote [localhost]: 
  Get "https://127.0.0.1:5555/1.0": 
    x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of 
      "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate 
       authority certificate "root@nimbus")
```

(Text wrapped for clarity)

This even happens after `lxc remote add nimbus 127.0.0.1:5555 --accept-certificate --password=xxxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: LXD caches the remote's cert in `~/.config/lxc/servercerts`, so just remove the relevant file.